# How is the zero set of an affine transform a vector subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces

An affine transform $T$ is defined as $T(x)=a(x)+b$, where $a(x)$ is a linear map, and $b$ is a vector.

An affine subspace is defined as the zero set of an affine transform.

How is the zero set of an affine transform a subspace? For example, take $p,q\in K$, where $K$ is the zero set of the affine transform $T$. Then $a(p)+b=a(q)+b=0$. However, $T(a+b)=a(p)+a(q)+b=a(q)=-b$.

How is the zero set of $T$ a subspace then?

Answer (score 2):

It is an *affine* subspace, not a linear (or vector) subspace. An *affine* subspace can be defined as the zero set of an affine transform or equivalently as a translated vector subspace, that is a set of the form $x + U$, where $U \subseteq V$ is a vector subspace. If $T$ is an affine transform an $W$ is zero set, then either $W$ is empty, or $w_0 \in W$. Then $W - w_0$ is a linear subspace.